# Using Scaffold-DbContext with user secrets

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to reverse engineer a db context using EF Core 3.0 as suggested in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding) document. It suggests that you can put your connection string into a user secret, and then run:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=my_key Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

I've tried initialising the user secrets as follows:

```
dotnet user-secrets init
dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings.my_key "Data Source=........... etc."
```

and then running the above command, I also also tried this (as I was using the PMC tools)

```
Scaffold-DbContext Name=my_key Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

but both give me the same error:

> A named connection string was used, but the name '*my_key*' was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is wrong. You need to include the "ConnectionStrings" prefix in the command as follows:

```
Scaffold-DbContext Name=ConnectionStrings.my_key Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```